# Exclude iPhone 4/4S from App Build

Tags: ios, iphone, build, armv7

I searched all over stackoverflow (and tested all finded solutions) but didn't find working solution for me.
I'd like to exclude iPhone 4/4S from build/app.

I tried the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities trick with armv7 exception but didn't work because when I submit the app I received error like:

```
ERROR ITMS-90502: "Invalid Bundle. Apps that only contain the arm64 slice must also have 'arm64' in the list of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist.
```

or:

```
ERROR ITMS-90098: "This bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities contains value 'arm64' which is incompatible with the MinimumOSVersion value of '8.0'."
```

Is there any updated solution/trick to solve?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
The question is marked as duplicated but I can't find equal question with fully working solution updated to today... :(

Answer (score 1):

The [iPhone 4 does not support iOS 8](http://iossupportmatrix.com/), so make iOS 8 the deployment target.

Comment: Thanks for your quickly answer. I edited the question, I mean 4/4S... It's a "design" question... many thanks! :)